# Adding automatic id for submit button added posts using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that allows user to post several posts added, when they click on submit button several times.

I made a template for post container using HTML and gave it an automatic `id` using JavaScript, but the post container added when the user clicks on the submit button doesn't take an automatic `id`. How can I solve this using JavaScript?

**Below is my JS and HTML snippet**:

```js
var myPost = document.querySelectorAll('.post-container'); //post container
var myDelBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.delete'); // delete icon

// loop for give id automatic
for (var i = 0; i < myPost.length; i++) {
  myPost[i].id = 'post-' + i;
  myDelBtn[i].id = 'post-' + i + '-delete';
};

function storeData() {
  var big = document.getElementById("contain"); // big container to append  new jumbotron child
  var postData = document.getElementById("comment").value; //value in text area
  var nDate = new Date().toLocaleString(); //convert date to day and hour format
  console.log(big);
  console.log(nDate);
  console.log(postData);

  // new jumborton template
  var newPost = '<div class="jumbotron post-container" id=" + myPost+">' +
    '<div class="media">' +
    '<a href="https://placeholder.com"><img  class="mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64"></a>' +
    '<a class="font" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete" id="+ myDelBtn+"></i></a>' +
    '<div class="media-body">' +
    '<h4 class="mt-0 mb-0">Username</h4>' +
    '<span class="date text-muted">' + nDate + '</span>' +
    '<div class="text-justify mt-2">' + postData + '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>';
  big.innerHTML += newPost;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>java-task</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container" id="wrapper">
    <div class="chatting-bot">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-4 mt-4"> Chatting System</h1>
      <form class="jumbotron pt-3" method="post">
        <div class="form-group row ">
          <label for="comment">Write Your Post</label>
          <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="write your post"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="storeData()">Post</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="posts" id="contain">
      <div class="jumbotron post-container" id="post-">
        <div class="media">
          <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img class="mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64"></a>
          <a class="font" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete " id="post-0-delete"></i></a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="mt-0 mb-0">Username</h4>
            <span class="date text-muted "> Posted on 7/14/2018, 11:10:05 am</span>
            <div class="text-justify mt-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="jumbotron post-container" id="post-">
        <div class="media">
          <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img class="mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64"></a>
          <a class="font" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete" id=""></i></a>
          <div class="media-body">
            <h4 class="mt-0 mb-0">Username</h4>
            <span class="date text-muted "> Posted on 7/14/2018, 11:10:05 am</span>
            <div class="text-justify mt-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
              book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your var `myPost` & `myDelBtn` are initialized at the first loading of the page. And your loop is called only one time just after. Thus, the loop affect an id for the 2 `.post-container` and then nothing.

In order to achieve this iterate id, you can imagine to create a counter with the number of articles at the beginning, then add +1 each time you add a post. And enter this new count id directly during the HTML generation.

ps : If you really want a loop to affect id, you can create a function, inside, you declare the new number of `.post-container`, use your loop and then you call it after HTML generation. But I think it's not the best option to re-affect id each time your user create a new post.

Example :

```js
var myPost = document.querySelectorAll('.post-container'); //post container
var count = myPost.length;  // initialize counter
var myDelBtn=document.querySelectorAll('.delete'); // delete icon

// loop for give id automatic
 for (var i=0; i< myPost.length; i++){
   console.log(myPost.length);
     myPost[i].id = 'post-' + i;
     myDelBtn[i].id='post-'+i +'-delete';
 };




function storeData() {
    var big=document.getElementById("contain");   // big container to append  new jumbotron child
    var postData = document.getElementById("comment").value;  //value in text area
    var nDate = new Date().toLocaleString(); //convert date to day and hour format
    console.log(big);
    console.log(nDate);
    console.log(postData);
    count = count + 1;   // id counter
    console.log(count);
    // use counter directly inside HTML parsing
    var newPost = '<div class="jumbotron post-container" id="post-'+ count +'">'+
        '<div class="media">'+
        '<a href="https://placeholder.com"><img  class="mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64"></a>'+
        '<a class="font" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete" id="post-'+ count + 'myDelBtn"></i></a>'+
        '<div class="media-body">'+
        '<h4 class="mt-0 mb-0">Username</h4>'+
        '<span class="date text-muted">'+ nDate +'</span>'+
        '<div class="text-justify mt-2">'+ postData +'</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';
    big.innerHTML += newPost;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>java-task</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id ="wrapper">
            <div class="chatting-bot">
                <h1 class="text-center mb-4 mt-4"> Chatting System</h1>
                <form class="jumbotron pt-3" method="post">
                    <div class="form-group row ">
                        <label for="comment">Write Your Post</label>
                        <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="form-control" rows="3" placeholder="write your post"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="storeData()">Post</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="posts" id="contain">
                <div class="jumbotron post-container" id="post-0">
                        <div class="media">
                            <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img  class="mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64"></a>
                            <a class="font" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete " id="post-0-delete"></i></a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="mt-0 mb-0">Username</h4>
                                <span class="date text-muted "> Posted on 7/14/2018, 11:10:05 am</span>
                                <div class="text-justify mt-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="jumbotron post-container" id="post-1">
                        <div class="media">
                            <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img  class="mr-3 rounded-circle" src="http://via.placeholder.com/64x64"></a>
                            <a class="font" href="#"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt delete" id="post-1-delete"></i></a>
                            <div class="media-body">
                                <h4 class="mt-0 mb-0">Username</h4>
                                <span class="date text-muted "> Posted on 7/14/2018, 11:10:05 am</span>
                                <div class="text-justify mt-2">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>


    <script src="js/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </body>
```